why can init array in struct with array-name in C
Bellow code is for 'init array element in strcut'

I have doubt about .name, why it is not .name[10] = "Bob", because it is like char arrary_name = {...} instead of char array_name[#] = {...}

(updated) after reading the comments/answers, now I know this format is 'Designated initialization' in C99
typedef struct 
{
    char name[10];
    char age;
}Man;


void main()
{

    Man man1 = 
    {
        .name = "Bob", // why not .name[10] = "Bob",
        .age = 18
    };

    printf("%s\n", man1.name); // "Bob"
    printf("%d\n", man1.age);  // 18

}


How is the man2 example less clear than the man1 example?  It's just explicitly calling out the field being initialized.

seems 'array_name (pointer): name is the name of the array field, it is not a pointer or an expression at all in the .name =  initializer syntax. (It is not a pointer in an expression either. In an expression it has an array type.)

printf("%s\n", man2) should be printf("%s\n", man2.name)

You don't understand the member designation and string initialization syntax.  That is statement of fact, not a question, and I am not sure there is anything we can do to help you understand it.

What is it you don't understand about the syntax?

Don't change the question.  It invalidates comments and answer.  Only edit the question to clarify it or add additional data.

See C23 Standard - 6.7.10 Initialization (p8 through end) and the examples that are part of that section.


I have doubt about .name, why it is not .name[10] = "Bob"

It is unclear to me why you think it should be .name[10] = "Bob", so I will try to answer it in a few different ways.

Because the declaration char name[10]; does not create a member called "name[10]";  it creates a member called "name", and the type of that member is char[].

Because the type of "Bob" is char[], so you can only use it to initialize another char[], you cannot use it to initialize a char.

Because the type of name is char[], therefore the type of name[10] is char, so you cannot initialize it with anything but another char.

Because name[10] should not be initialized with anything anyway, because it is one position past the end of the array. (Valid indexes are 0 to 9, this does not include 10.)




I understand int array[4] = {#,#,#,#}, but in above example, it is like int array = {#,#,#}, seems 'array_name (pointer) = value'

There is not partial initialization in C.  Initialization initializes all members of man.  All not explicitly members are initialize to 0.
OP's declaration and initialization of type Man is complete in all cases.

man3.name = {'A', 'B', 'C'}, initializes all of man3.

Yes, man2 is completely initialized as if
    Man man2 = 
    {
        .name = { 'B' , 'o' 'b', 0, 0 ,0, 0 ,0, 0, 0};
        .age = 18
    };


When declaring a plain array in C and initializing it, you do two things at once: declaration and initialization. So you'd either have to do char name[10] = "Bob", in which case the array is going to be 10 items large, or alternatively char name[] = "Bob"; in which case the array will become just as long as the string "Bob" and the null terminator, 4 bytes.
If you would only declare an array without initializing it - char name[10]; - then you wouldn't be able to directly assign a string to it later because the way C was designed, it doesn't allow arrays to be directly assigned. You'd have to use strcpy/memcpy.
With structs you have three steps: declaration of the struct type (optionally done with typedef), declaration of an instance of that struct type and initialization. And since you already decide the size of the array during declaration of the struct type, you don't need to mention that later - it is now fixed to 10 items, take it or leave it.
There are two ways to initialize a struct object when declaring the instance. Either:
Man man1 = 
{
  "Bob",
  18
};

Or with designated initializers:
Man man1 = 
{
    .name = "Bob",
    .age = 18
};

These are 100% equivalent but the latter version is perhaps clearer and more readable. In either case the name member is already set to be 10 items large. So something like .name[] = "Bob" won't work, that syntax isn't supported.

Also note that there are even designated initializers for array items as well. So this (cumbersome) way of initializing is valid too:
Man man1 = 
{
  .name = { [0]='B', [1]='o', [2]='b', [3]='\0' },
  .age = 18
};

But again, name is already an array of 10 items no matter how many of them we initialize explicitly.
Designated initializers for arrays aren't particularly helpful/readable when dealing with strings, but could be useful in other contexts.

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but here's a go.
.x = y is there for the convenience of the programmer. It's so they don't have to remember the exact ordering of the declaration of the struct, and so the struct members can be reordered without breaking code.
These all do the same thing.
    Man man1 = 
    {
        .name = "Bob",
        .age = 18
    };

    Man man2 = 
    {
        .age = 18,
        .name = "Bob"
    };

    Man man3 = 
    {
        "Bob",
        18
    };

They all say to assign "Bob" to the char name[10] field, and to assign 18 to the char age field.
Demonstration.
    Man man4 = 
    {
        18,
        "Bob"
    };

man4 is different. The order of the arguments matters. man4 assigns 18 to the char name[10] field and "Bob" to the char age field resulting in undefined behavior.
Demonstration.
